# Google Analytics API: problems extracting some data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How do I use this API? I can extract some data, but not all of it... I'm a bit lost and I can't find any examples in the documentation. I'm using gapi.class.php.

I have code such as:

```
$ga = new gapi('user','pwd');

    $ga->requestReportData('id',array('browser'),array('pageviews','visits', 'timeOnSite'));
    var_dump($ga);
    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
    {
     print_r($result);
      echo '<strong>'.$result.'</strong><br />';
      echo 'Pageviews: ' . $result->getPageviews() . ' ';
      echo 'Visits: ' . $result->getVisits() . '<br />';
      echo 'Time On site: ' . $result->getTimeOnSite() . '<br />';
    }

    echo '<p>Total pageviews: ' . $ga->getPageviews() . ' total visits: ' . $ga->getVisits() . '</p>';
```

The above is working, but then I also want to get other data such as goals... I see this: http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/dimsmets/dimsmets.html

but I'm not really sure how to call each function, or property... I'm really lost, any examples would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

GAPI uses magic get methods. You put in the dimensions and metrics that you want and get them using the magic get methods.

For example:

```
$ga = new gapi('user','pwd');

    $ga->requestReportData('id',array('browser'),array('pageviews','visits', 'timeOnSite'));

   foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
      {
       print_r($result);
     echo '<strong>'.$result.'</strong><br />';
     echo 'Pageviews: ' . $result->getPageviews() . ' ';
     echo 'Visits: ' . $result->getVisits() . '<br />';
     echo 'Time On site: ' . $result->getTimeOnSite() . '<br />';
   }

   echo '<p>Total pageviews: ' . $ga->getPageviews() . ' total visits: ' . $ga->getVisits() . '</p>';
```

`array('browser')` is the dimension and   `array('pageviews','visits', 'timeOnSite')` are the metrics. `$result->getPageviews()` is the magic get method for the `pageviews` metric.

So, [refer to the list](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/dimsmets/dimsmets.html) and put in the dimensions and metrics you want then return them using the magic get methods of `getYourdimension` or `getYourmetric`. Note that `get` is lowercase and the dimension or metric begins with a capital letter.

[See the documentation for more information](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/):

> Access metrics and dimensions using magic get methods
>   With GAPI, when data is returned from Google it is automatically converted into a native PHP object, with an interface to allow the 'get' the value of any dimesion or metric.
>
> For example, if you request the metric 'uniquePageviews' and the dimesion 'pagePath' you can do the following:

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  echo $result->getUniquePageviews();
  echo $result->getPagePath();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I´m using that and all goal data comes as zero (goalCompletions, goalConversions, etc)... Any ideas? (my data is not 0 when looking at the analytics page)

Comment: @luqita Check the date range. Make sure there is data for the date range you have selected in gapi.